# SQL Adding an aggregated column to base

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add a combined total to each group. I have written 2 queries which work right, but I need to add the result of the second query into the first.

First one is:

```
SELECT     name_id
         , take
         , id_user
FROM       ((Proizv
             INNER JOIN Izdan
                     ON Proizv.id = Izdan.id_proizv)
            INNER JOIN Exzemp
                    ON Izdan.id = Exzemp.id_izdan)
INNER JOIN log
        ON Exzemp.id = log.id_exzemp
WHERE      take IN ( SELECT TOP 2 take
                     FROM   log AS s
                     WHERE  s.id_user = log.id_user
                     ORDER  BY take DESC );
```

There I take latest two cases from each group.

The second one is:

```
SELECT     COUNT(name_id) AS cname
         , name_id
FROM       ((Proizv
             INNER JOIN Izdan
                     ON Proizv.id = Izdan.id_proizv)
            INNER JOIN Exzemp
                    ON Izdan.id = Exzemp.id_izdan)
INNER JOIN log
        ON Exzemp.id = log.id_exzemp
GROUP      BY name_id;
```

There I take aggregated column which I want to add to results of the first one table by name_id(initial tables are the same).

When I try simply to join them, I get an error.

Can anyone help with this?
Thanks!

Comment: I use SQL-server

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
With a as (
SELECT     name_id
         , take
         , id_user
FROM       ((Proizv
             INNER JOIN Izdan
                     ON Proizv.id = Izdan.id_proizv)
            INNER JOIN Exzemp
                    ON Izdan.id = Exzemp.id_izdan)
INNER JOIN log
        ON Exzemp.id = log.id_exzemp
WHERE      take IN ( SELECT TOP 2 take
                     FROM   log AS s
                     WHERE  s.id_user = log.id_user
                     ORDER  BY take DESC )
),
b as (
SELECT     COUNT(name_id) AS cname
         , name_id
FROM       ((Proizv
             INNER JOIN Izdan
                     ON Proizv.id = Izdan.id_proizv)
            INNER JOIN Exzemp
                    ON Izdan.id = Exzemp.id_izdan)
INNER JOIN log
        ON Exzemp.id = log.id_exzemp
GROUP      BY name_id
)
select a.*, b.cname
from a inner join b
  on a.name_id = b.name_id
```